# Why does order in method declaration matter?

Tags: java

I didn't notice before until unconsciously misplaced `void` with `main`.

```
 public static main void (String[] args){

 }
```

Why does it give me an error?

Comment: Grammar.........

Comment: It's basic method syntax. It's the way Java methods are defined.

Comment: matters method main in order why beginner Java?

Comment: @ Peter I don't consider myself higher yet

Comment: @Durdona The order of words tells you their significance.  If you see `aaa bbb(ccc ddd)` you know that the method `bbb` takes an argument of type `ccc` called `ddd` and returns a value of type `aaa

Comment: So...why does this question need to be closed?  This doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [method syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4) (specified by the Java Language Specification) mandates it as such:

```
 MethodDeclaration:
     MethodHeader MethodBody

 MethodHeader:
     MethodModifiers (opt) TypeParameters (opt) Result MethodDeclarator Throws (opt)

 MethodDeclarator:
     Identifier ( FormalParameterList (opt) )
```

A brief overview:

- A method declaration consists of a method header and a method body.
- A method header consists of modifiers (which are optional, type parameters (optional as well), the result (be it a primitive type, `void`, or another `Object`), and the method declarator.  A throws can be provided (which is also optional).
- The method declarator consists of some sort of identifier; this is typically described as the name of the method with whatever formal arguments (if any).

Let's apply this to the valid declaration of `main`:

```
public static  void      main     (String[] args)
   ^    ^       ^         ^              ^
  modifiers   result  identifier  parameter list
```

If you alter the order (let's take your example), then you wind up with this:

```
public static  main      void     (String[] args)
   ^    ^       ^          ^           ^
  modifiers   result  identifier  parameter list
```

Wait a second.  `main` isn't a valid result.  And `void` isn't a valid identifier (which is the more egregious error of the two; reserved words [can't be used as identifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html)).

This is why the order matters; Java is intentionally parsing the order of the elements to see if they make syntactic sense.  Introducing an order-agnostic declaration would be *extremely* confusing to anyone reading code, and would likely violate long-held conventions of method declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are trying to create a method named `void` which has a output type of `main` in it.

This is simply not valid. Swap `main` with `void`.

If you need more information about defining methods try the [java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html). There is a thorough explanation of method signatures in them.

Comment: I was going to say symbol instead but it seems that I was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, method declarations have six components, in order:

Modifiers : specifies how your method is visible to outsiders

such as public(available to all) private(available only inside class), and others like static.

The return type — what value the method returns : ex if method returns 10 then we can use int as a return type. or void if the method does not return a value.

The method name— name of the method which we can give but for main. it should be main always as its going to be called by JVM automatically.

The parameter list in parenthesis—a comma-delimited list of input parameters, preceded by their data types, enclosed by parentheses, (). If there are no parameters, you must use empty parentheses.

An exception list—added after method name using throw keyword.

The method body, enclosed between braces—the method's code, including the declaration of local variables, goes here.

for more info check here
[java methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Comment: *An exception list—to be discussed later* later when? This is a direct text copy/paste from the link you're posted. Quote it or write your own text based on the info from that link, otherwise it should be removed for plagiarism.